# DVB Recording of a channel

Tags: directshow

I'm trying to record a DVB-Channel with a DVB-T Tuner.
I already did much research on this topic but I don't get really "information" what to do.

Basically I'm already able to create a own Graph with the default `GraphEdit`, make a tune request and watch a channel. Converting the Graph to C# Code with the `DirectShowLib` or to C++ isn't a big problem for me.

But what I don't know, what is the right approach to record the movie. (Without decode it to mpeg / avi and so on.)

Comment: Do you want to record the original (MPEG-TS) stream? The whole stream, or just one channel?

Comment: Principally just one Channel... but the difference between "just one channel" and the original TS Stream isnt clear for me ?

Comment: A TS stream can have multiple programs (channels) listed inside of it. So, for example, if you had two channels each with audio and video, there would be four streams multiplexed in the TS stream, one video and one audio per channel. So if you record the whole original stream, you would get both programs at the same time. Otherwise, you would have to split out the channel you were interested in and then reencode the audio/video into some container format and then save that container.

Answer (score 0):

The most important parts of the graph are some tuning related filters, they connect to the demultiplexer (demux), and the demux will output a video and audio stream.

The easiest way to get the mpeg stream is putting a filter before the demux. For example a samplegrabber. There you will receive the complete transport stream as it is broadcasted. But that normally contains [multiple programs](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aMPEG_Transport_Stream_HL.svg) which are multiplexed on the same frequency. If you only need one program, you need to filter the other programs out of the stream.

If you only need a single program, it is probably easier to directly connect the audio and video stream coming out of the demultiplexer, to a multiplexer, and write it's output to a file. You need to make sure there is no decoder or any other filter between the demux and the mux. The problem is that you need to find a directshow multiplexer, as windows does not contain a standard multiplexer. I don't know any free multiplexer.

What you also can do is write the audio and video directly to a file. (again without decoding, or anything else). Then use for example ffmpeg to join the audio and video to a single file.

```
C:\> ffmpeg -i input.m2v -i input.mp2 -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.mpg
```

You probably also need to delay the audio or video stream to get them in sync.

One addition, of course you can also use ffmpeg to [convert](http://howto-pages.org/ffmpeg/#map) the multi program transport stream to a single program stream.

Comment: So i need only a part of the TS - Stream, because i want only one channel! I already have the tuning related filter in the graph, because i already see with the Video Mixing Rendering Filter a TV Signal. Do i understand right i have principally write a own DirectShow filter which writes all the data out of the MPEG 2 Demultiplexer to a file ? (Video+Audio?)

Comment: You either have to find a multiplex filter (or create it yourself) and use a filewriter to write the output to a file. Or use two filewriters to write the audio and video separately to two files, and multiplex them afterwards (not in directshow). But if you can't find a good multiplexer, it is easier to add a samplegrabber filter before the dexultiplexer, and write everything to a file except the PIDs you don't need. If you do that you should change the PAT, but nothing will go wrong if you don't change the PAT. iso13818-1 contains technical info about mpeg-ts.

Comment: Ok thanks for all suggestion! I have wrote a own directshow filter and connected it with a callback with my C# Application and there i can do with the TS-Steam whatever i want... just a few lines of code :-)